# Choose Extended Class on Runtime C#

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Good Evening to Everyone,

I have 2 abstract classes in C# :

```
public abstract class A
{

}

public abstract class B
{

}
```

I want in my third Class to decide on run time through the config file to either extend Class A or Class B.

For Example :

```
public Class C : B or A
```

Both of the abstract classes provide one abstract method with the same Signature .

Comment: You can use if loop with the flag specified in config file

Comment: What about the implementation of the abstract method?

Comment: Please explain what you are actually trying to achieve. This sounds very like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Just to be absolutely clear - you cannot do what you have asked. Inheritance is a compile-time feature - you cannot change it at runtime (weeellll...technically you could generate a brand new class on the fly, but that is almost never an appropriate answer!)

Comment: This not a problem the implementation is the same in both cases.To be more clear the first class is the implementation of a TCP Listener and  the  second class in the implementation of an SSL TCP Listener. I want to choose in run time if i will use the TCP Listener Class or the SSL TCP Listener Instead of changing the class in my code and rebuilding the Project .

Comment: What is your original problem? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: @ChristosCharalampidis Then you want your class C to accept an `IListener` in it's constructor, and you get both `A` and `B` to implement an `IListener` interface. Search for "inheritance vs composition" for more information.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change/chose base class at run-time as base class is defined at compile time.

It sounds like implementing common interface in both classes and using just interface everywhere else would be good solution in your case.

```
interface IListener 
{
     void Listen();
     ...
}

class CA : A, IListener{ .... }
class CB : B, IListener { .... }

// to use:
IListner listener =  useSSL ? new CA(...) : new CB(...);
```

Comment: @CodeNotFound you can create new class at run time but you can't change base class at run-time.

Comment: ha ! I deleted my first comment. Yep that is what I think :D

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly from your question and the comments (check what @RB said), the appropriate behavior would be to define:

```
public interface IC
{
}

public class A : IC
{
}

public class B : IC
{
}
```

Write your code to consume the Interface, and contrive a way to inject the correct concrete class into the consumer.